# Removing an object from an array in (geo)json using Java

Tags: java, json, polygon, geojson

I have a geojson (a json for georeferenced data) with one "features"-array, containing many polygons. I want to loop through the elements in the "features"-array and remove some of them(which have a polygon-area smaller than 70.0). This is the structure of my geojson:

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",

   "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DN": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 5117.0, 0.0 ], [ 5117.0, 1.0 ], [ 5124.0, 1.0 ], [ 5117.0, 0.0 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DN": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 149.0 ], [ 0.0, 150.0 ], [ 61.0, 150.0 ], [ 0.0, 149.0 ] ] ] } }
   ]
}
```

Here I try to loop through the elements of the "features"-array, calculate the areas of each polygon and remove it if its area is less than 70.0:

```
public static void smallPolygonRemover() throws IOException, ParseException{
        // read geojson
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("source.geojson");
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray features = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("features");

        for (int j = 0; j < features.size(); j++) {
              JSONObject firstFeature = (JSONObject) features.get(j);
              JSONObject geometry = (JSONObject) firstFeature.get("geometry");
              JSONArray coordinates = (JSONArray) geometry.get("coordinates");
              // area(coordinate) calculates the area of the polygon with given coordinates
              if(area(coordinates)<70.0){
                    features.remove(firstFeature);
              }
        }
        // write the edited geojson to a file
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Removed.geojson");
        writer.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
        writer.close();
}
```

The problem is: Polygons which should be removed are still there but other polygons are gone. Do I use `features.remove(firstFeature);` wrong? I also tried `features.remove(features);` but no use.. The other possibility is that the area-function is wrong ( I use [this](https://github.com/jillesvangurp/geogeometry/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jillesvangurp/geo/GeoGeometry.java) one) or maybe there are problems with doubles.

Comment: Check your code. You put the points into the variable `coordinates` (with `s`) and then call `area()` with `coordinate`. Is that a typo in the question or is the actual code wrong?

Comment: It was a typo but my original code uses coordinates. So the typo was only here. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interaction between the loop and `remove()` which you've missed: If you remove an entry in the array, then the indexes of all further elements change. That means if you remove item #2, then item #3 becomes #2. Your loop then sets the index to 3 which means you never check item #3 and continue with the old #4 instead.

Remove the `j++` from the loop and use this code instead:

```
 if(area(coordinate)<70.0){
     features.remove(firstFeature);
     // removing the polygon moves j+1 to j, so we need to leave j alone
 } else {
     j++; // this polygon is OK, move to the next one
 }
```

or start the iteration with `features.size()-1` and count down.

Comment: That seems to go toward the right direction but there is still something wrong. With `System.out.println(area(coordinates));` I found out that the biggest Polygon has an area of 2932899.1 . So I changed the if-block to: `if(area(coordinates)<2932899.0){
                    features.remove(firstFeature);
                    j--;
              }`
to get a geojson with only the biggest polygon. But I get an Exception at `JSONObject firstFeature = (JSONObject) features.get(j);` The Error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

Comment: The code should do `j++` after each loop. Therefore, it shouldn't be possible to get a `-1` index with the code above (for the first element, `j` would be `-1` at the end of the loop, then `j++` would turn that into `0`). Another solution would be to remove the increment in the loop and use `if(area...) {...} else { j ++; }`. If nothing else helps, you need to debug the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: moving the j++ from the loop head under the if-block did it! And I found out that the area function calculates the area around 60% less then it would be.. Uhm maybe you should edit your answer so I can accept it (or is it ok so since it is in the comment section?)

Comment: @Selphiron: I've edited my answer but still the `else j++;` shouldn't be necessary unless you do something else in your loop.

Comment: hmm no I don't have an else branch. j++ is being executed regardless of the if block. Should I put it in an else branch?

Comment: @Selphiron: Think some more about it. Maybe draw an image how the array changes and what `j` should be at different points in time.

Comment: now I got it. Please change it one last time:  I put j++; to the loop-head and added j--; right after features.remove... . No else branch. The exception had another cause.

Comment: Actually, I like my solution with the else better since it makes it very clear that this loop is different from the usual ones.

Comment: all right than. I tried and it worked too. Thanks :)